# How to send data from page with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html

I have two similar forms on same page expected to make ajax call to same Flask function. How to get data from form whose button was clicked? I tried using `document.getElementsByName()` to get values of elements in submitted form, then include it in data to be sent via ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<form  name="contact1" id="contact1">    
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name1"   required /></div> 
    <div>Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email1"  required /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div> 
</form>
<form name="contact2" id="contact2">    
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name2"   required /></div> 
    <div>Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email2"  required /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div> 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        var  name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
        var  email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/contact',
            data: {
              name: name,
              email: email
            },
            success: function (data) {  
                $('#results').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                $('#result').html(error);           
        }
    });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can keep one hidden field in each form with different name, this will help you to identify form, or even form name will also work.

Comment: Easy way out give the form fileds ids and on submit use the this key word to reference the fileds

Comment: @Mowzey not with one submit. The form needs to use class or name attribute to get its field

Comment: On submit of form using jQuery var email= $(this).find('email'); am positive it will get values for only the submitted form

Comment: @mplungjan clean , thank you

Comment: Nope. `var email= $(this).find('email')` would find a tag named email.

Comment: `var email = $(this).find("[name=email"]).val()` would work the same as my suggetion `var email = $("[name=email]",this).val();`

Comment: You can get ID on form submit and based on that, you can decide that what to do or where to send data. Regarding fields you may access like `var name = $("[name=name]",this).val()` using `this` means the submitted form field will be fetched.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I believe my suggestion of using `var name = $("[name=name]",this).val()` instead of `name= this.id=="form1"?$("#name1").val(): $("#name2").val()` is a little more generic.

Comment: @mplungjan Yup I agreed. saying to get ID of submitted form is to not because of getting its relevant field but to decide that if contact1 submitted then go to page-abc and if contact2 submitted then go to page xyz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use jQuery: 
   `var name = $("[name=name]",this).val();` - or give them a class and use `$(".name",this).val()`
2. Rename the submit button - name="submit" will hide the form's submit method
3. Use preventDefault() to not actually submit the form

---

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    var name = $("[name=name]",this).val(); // the field that belongs to "this" form
    var email = $("[name=email]",this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/contact',
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
        $('#result').html(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```